# Align right in excel using html style

Tags: html, excel, xls

I am using a html file to create an excel file and everything works just fine but the text-align. I want to format my data to text and align it right(left is the default).
Something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.textclass { font-weight: bold; mso-number-format:"\@"; text-align:"right"}
</style>
```

With this solution the bold font and the format is good, but text is still aligned left.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Try float:right

Comment: float:right not working :/

Comment: ,could you please try adding display:block

Comment: Sorry and thanks, both version are working. I substituted text-align:right with float:right instead of using them together. Together they are working. So are   text-align:right with display:block.

Comment: Glad that it is working :) I have posted my comment as answer, please mark   it as answer it helped you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

**float:right**

or

**display:block**

Issue seems to be that the textclass element is an inline element that is not allowing text-align:right

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Just use:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .textclass { font-weight: bold; mso-number-format:"\@"; text-align: right}
</style>
```

Without quotes.

Probably your changes won´t be reflect it until you clean your browser cache:

[Chrome](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

[Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache)

Comment: I tried it before and now again but unfortunately this is not a solution.

Comment: Odd... Did you clean the browser cache as well?